# Terraform helm chart how to pass value?

Tags: terraform, kubernetes-helm

I'm totally lost in my mind to understand how I can pass a value of command-line flags for now. Could someone to prompt me, please? I would like to have TCP6 enabled.

The helm chart has value is:

```yaml
server:
  env: []
```

My code is:

```json
resource "helm_release" "victoria_metrics" {
  name        = var.vm_release_name
  ...

  dynamic "set" {
    for_each = {
      "server.env" = "-enableTCP6"
    }
    content {
      name  = set.key
      value = set.value
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not so clear what you want to achive with your code, i think to understand that you want to set the -`enableTCP6` flag, like i can see in the [DOC](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/helm/latest/docs/resources/release#example-usage---chart-repository) you should do:

```
resource "helm_release" "victoria_metrics" {
  name        = var.vm_release_name
  ...

  dynamic "set" {
    for_each = {
      "enableTCP6" = "true"
    }
    content {
      name  = each.key
      value = each.value
    }
  }
}
```

If you can share which is the helm chart you are trying to apply I'll try to be more helpful

Comment: Thank you Danilo. However, in this case it won't do what I need. It looks I should use something like this.
  values = [
    "${file("values.yaml")}"
  ]

It isn't exactly what I wish, but should work. This solution means I should maintain values.yaml by himself.

Comment: What is inside the values.yaml is also configurable by SET block, are you sure is the only solution?

Comment: Ain't sure, but I don't know any way how to pass a set of values into helm values like this: `server:  env: []`

Comment: The helm chart is public or private? Can i look it?

Comment: It's public [VictoriaMetrics values.yaml](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/helm-charts/blob/master/charts/victoria-metrics-single/values.yaml)